# Printing character from boot loader

Tags: bootloader

I am trying to print character from boot loader using code

```
[BITS 16]   ;Tells the assembler that its a 16 bit code
[ORG 0x7C00]    ;Origin, tell the assembler that where the code will
    ;be in memory after it is been loaded

MOV AL, 65
CALL PrintCharacter
JMP $       ;Infinite loop, hang it here.


PrintCharacter: ;Procedure to print character on screen
    ;Assume that ASCII value is in register AL
MOV AH, 0x0E    ;Tell BIOS that we need to print one charater on screen.
MOV BH, 0x00    ;Page no.
MOV BL, 0x07    ;Text attribute 0x07 is lightgrey font on black background

INT 0x10    ;Call video interrupt
RET     ;Return to calling procedure

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ;Fill the rest of sector with 0
DW 0xAA55           ;Add boot signature at the end of bootloader
```

As directed in [Writing Hello World Bootloader](http://www.viralpatel.net/taj/tutorial/hello_world_bootloader.php). But it just hangs without printing anything. How can we debug this ? I have successfully created hanging boot loader using following code

```
[BITS 16]   ;tell the assembler that its a 16 bit code
[ORG 0x7C00]    ;Origin, tell the assembler that where the code will
;be in memory after it is been loaded

JMP $       ;infinite loop

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ;fill the rest of sector with 0
DW 0xAA55           ; add boot signature at the end of bootloader
```

I am testing my code on VMware 3.0.0 build-203739.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging real-mode X86, you can try the debugger integrated with Dosbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
[BITS 16]       ; We need 16-bit intructions for Real mode
[ORG 0x7C00]    ; The BIOS loads the boot sector into memory location
0x7C00
       mov ah, 0Eh     ; We want to print a single character
       mov al, 'A'     ; That character is 'A'
       mov bh, 0Eh     ; White text on black background, not blinking
       mov bl, 0       ; Page number 0
       int 10h

hang:
       jmp hang        ; Loop, self-jump

times 510-($-$$) db 0  ; Fill the rest of the files with zeros, until we reach 510 bytes
dw 0AA55h              ; Our boot sector identifyer
```

-
i successfully managed to run this code with the help of nasm and Bochs under windows.
Instructions :-
1)nasm -f bin booting.asm -o booting.bin
  The '-f bin' specifies the format to plain binary.
2)Copy the file into Bochs' directory and run it with the booting.bin as a floppy and we're done

I even tested it by burning the image of bin file on a flash drive and on booting that flash drive i was able to get what i expected. You can get all that info on
http://www.weethet.nl/english/hardware_bootfromusbstick.php